# Profile windows start-up time

Tags: windows, boot

As it happens, windows workstations get slow over time. Notably, users complain about slow start-up times. What is the scientific approach to identifying what impact what service/operation on start-up has on boot time or resource usage?

Answer (score 4):

Microsoft had a tool called BootVis. It's not officially supported anymore, but you can still find it around the net.

From [Fast Boot / Fast Resume Design](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/system/sysperf/fastboot/default.mspx):

> The design goals for Windows XP on a
> typical consumer PC are:
>
> - Boot to a useable state in a total of 30 seconds
> - Resume from Hibernate (S4) in a total of 20 seconds
> - Resume from Standby (S3) in a total of 5 seconds
>
> Boot and resume times are measured
> from the time the power switch is
> pressed to being able to start a
> program from a desktop shortcut.
>
> **About Bootvis.exe**
>
> Bootvis.exe is a
> performance tracing and visualization
> tool that Microsoft designed to help
> PC system designers and software
> developers identify performance issues
> for boot/resume timing while
> developing new PC products or
> supporting software.
>
> Please note that
> Bootvis.exe is not a tool that will
> improve boot/resume performance for
> end users. Contrary to some published
> reports, Bootvis.exe cannot reduce or
> alter a system's boot or resume
> performance. The boot optimization
> routines invoked by Bootvis.exe are
> built into Windows XP. These routines
> run automatically at pre-determined
> times as part of the normal operation
> of the operating system.
>
> ...
>
> The Bootvis.exe tool is no longer available from this site.

Comment: BootVIS crashed on my XP :) Any other tools you can recommend?

Comment: Nope, that was pretty much it. i did say that it was unsupported :)